# Replace ssl protocol on browser with custom protocol

Tags: ssl, browser

I was wondering if it would be possible to replace the current ssl in a browser, via a browser plugin or something like that, with a custom version of ssl.  Any ideas on if this is even possible?

Comment: For what purpose? So that you won't be able to browse to any HTTPS websites?

Comment: I have many different ideas but one of them is to use openssl that is custom for logging so I can monitor the traffic going through, and that would still allow me to browse HTTPS websites.

Comment: @PatrickDoherty: for this use case you don't need to replace anything. Just take the source of Chromium and fiddle with the included source of BoringSSL (which is a fork of OpenSSL) to do what you want.

Comment: That was just one idea, I have quite a few different ideas and most of them revolve around using a custom version of ssl and I just am wondering if that is at all possible.